# Find a simple formula for $\sum_{k=1}^{n}(5k + 1)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, analysis, summation

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(5k + 1) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}5k + \sum_{k=1}^{n}(1) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}5k + n = 5\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + n = 5n^2/2 + 5n/2 + n$$

Can something further be done ?

Comment: What more do you want done?

Comment: $5n/2+n=7n/2.{}{}{}$ So you can write it as: $$\frac{n(5n+7)}2.$$

Comment: More generally, of $f(1),\dots,f(n)$ is an arithmetic progression, the sum is $$\frac{n(f(1)+f(n))}2.$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That makes sense, thank you. Feel free to post your comment as an answer if you want so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series that you've given is just an arithmetic series, whose corresponding sequence is
$$ 5k + 1, 5(k+1) + 1, 5(k+2) + 1, …, 5(n) + 1 $$

Now, as $k$ varies from 1 to $n$, the sequence actually is:
$$ 6, 11, 16, 21, …, 5(n) + 1 $$

The sum of any arithmetic sequence is always:
$$ S_n = \frac{n}{2}\ [a + a_n], $$
where $S_n$ is the sum up to $n$ terms (starting from 1) and $a_n$ is the last term.

Here $ a = 6 $ and $ a_n = 5n + 1 $. Therefore,
$$ S_n = \frac {n}{2}\ [6 + (5n + 1)] = \frac {n}{2} [7 + 5n], $$
which should be what you're looking for.

Comment: @wengen if you're looking for how the formula for the sum up to $n$ terms of an arithmetic sequence actually comes, I can edit the answer and show you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! If you can, that would be awesome. But I also don't want to consume too much of your time either, I suppose it could probably be found on the internet

Comment: @wengen Yes, Wikipedia has proved the $S_n$ formula nicely: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum.